# Can not match date from database to current date with loop with php

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, codeigniter-3

before i ever ask this problem but there is another problem and i stuck here. I am trying to display the data of the day in the database, which day will be matched with the date of the month but I do not understand to make the script iteration, how to solve it?

MY TABLE

```
| id| Payment |  day | Month |  Year |
|___|_________|__ ___|_______|_______|
| 1 |  Mobile |  2   |   7   |  2018 |
| 2 |  Mobile |  3   |   7   |  2018 |
| 3 |  Mobile |  4   |   7   |  2018 |
| 4 |  Mobile |  5   |   7   |  2018 |
| 5 |  Mobile |  8   |   7   |  2018 |
| 6 |  Mobile |  9   |   7   |  2018 |
| 7 |  Mobile |  10  |   7   |  2018 |
| 8 |  Mobile |  11  |   7   |  2018 |
```

MY QUery

```
$q_day = $this->db->select('*')->from('payment_day')->where('Month', 7)->where('Year', 2018)->get()->result_array();

$day = 31;

for ($x = 1; $x <= $day; $x++) {
    foreach($q_day as $row){
        if($x == $row['day']){
            echo '<td>x</td>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>-</td>';
        }
    }
}
```

which I expect the result as the following table

```
| DAY | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | xxxxxx
|     | - | x | x | x | x | - | - | x | x |  x |  x |  - |  - | 14 | xxxxxx
```

Comment: `foreach($q_day as $row){` Once it's completed the loop, you're at the end of the record set; you'll need to reset to the beginning to loop through it again for each of the remaining 30 days

Comment: do i have to re loop @MarkBaker

Comment: You should look into mysql's `DATE` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can create **one array which key will be day** and then check **using if condition in loop.**

```
$q_day = $this->db->select('*')->from('payment_day')->where('Month', 7)->where('Year', 2018)->get()->result_array();
 //try create array from loop    
 $avaiableDays = [];
 foreach($q_day as $row){
   $avaiableDays[$row['day']] = $row;
 }

$day = 31;

for ($x = 1; $x <= $day; $x++) {
    if(!empty($avaiableDays[$x])){
           echo '<td>x</td>';
       }else{
           echo '<td>-</td>';
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You get result as array: `->result_array()` and then accessing it as object: `$row->day`

Comment: @Rainmx93 thanks for guiding :) i have updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @BinitGhetiya what if the days have multiple entries then older data may replaced in loop

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya i have answered on what users has asked in question.  If we think in that way then there can be lot's of scenarios.

Comment: thank you @Binit Ghetiya, this is resolved. but there are less turns should be this is the right one `if(!empty($avaiableDays[$x])){`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $q_day = $this->db->select('day')->from('payment_day')->where('Month', 7)->where('Year', 2018)->get()->result_array();

 $day = 31;

 for ($x = 1; $x <= $day; $x++) {
     in_array($x,$q_day){
        echo '<td>x</td>';
     }else{
        echo '<td>-</td>';
     }  
 }
```